# SQL- Add up Values in a Column

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I add up values in a SQL column? I have the table set up in xampp and I'm trying to add up all the values in a column titled "gross".

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! I've got it working and now have a follow-up question. Is there a way to add up only positive numbers in the column and then add up only negative numbers in the column. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**SQL Server or MySQL:**

```
select sum(MyColumn) as MyColumnSum from MyTable
```

**If you need to sum a column by a grouping of another column**

```
select sum(MyColumn) as MyColumnSum, OtherColumn from MyTable Group By OtherColumn
```

**Here is a way to, separately, add up negative or positive numbers**

```
select
  sum( case when MyColumn < 0 then MyColumn else 0 end ) as NegativeSum,
  sum( case when MyColumn > 0 then MyColumn else 0 end ) as PositiveSum
from
  MyTable
```

**Reference**

- [MySQL Reference for SUM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

Comment: Since he mentions xampp, it's MySQL, but the query should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(yourCol) as Gross
from YourTable
```

Use the aggregate function SUM().

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`SUM()` function documentation for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

```
SELECT    YourRecordID,
          SUM(Gross) AS GrossSum
FROM      YourTable
GROUP BY  YourRecordID
```