# SQL sum all values in column

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate-functions

I have table with 500+ rows and I want to sum all the values in a column.

Example:

```
 name  | number
 ----------------
 name1 | 25
 name2 | 10
 name3 | 5
 name4 | 20
```

The total sum is: 60

I can do that via PHP but is this possible using an SQL query?

Comment: The `sum()` is 60, and that is a big hint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL- Add up Values in a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334686/sql-add-up-values-in-a-column)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `sum()`:

```
select sum(number) as total_number
from mytable
```

Comment: i dont know why i actualy didint think about this ‍♂️