# how to sum a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am multiplying two columns of my view `vDetalleEventoCaracteristicas` and showing it in the Total column but now I want to sum all the records of the Total column

How could I do that?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL sum all values in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64564649/sql-sum-all-values-in-column)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total_Sum
FROM (
    SELECT *,(Cantidad * valor) AS Total
    FROM vDetalleEventoCaracteristicas
    WHERE idevento = @IdEvento
)table_alis
```

Use this query you will get sum of Total column.

Comment: Hello, the following returns to me Msg 1050, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
This syntax is only allowed for parameterized queries.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 21
Must declare the scalar variable "@IdEvento".

Comment: @douglas you have already declared that parameter according to your code. This answer is only dealing with the query, not the entire SP which isn't relevant to the issue.

Comment: Although a derived table alias will be required.

Comment: @DaleK now I get this error "incorrect syntax near ')'. Expecting ID, QUOTED_ID "

Answer (score 3):

just add SUM to your select statement:

```
select SUM(Cantidad * Valor) AS Total from vDetalleEventoCaracteristicas
where  idevento = @IdEvento
```